# What should I check? Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyFunctionName' of undefined URL

Tags: javascript, vb6, chromium-embedded

The problem only occurs in the compiled application, so I guess it's a browser specific specific problem, but I'm not sure:

I have added the following script to a webpage:

```
async function exportChatAsXMLHelper(params){
    let displayname     = params[0];
    let includeMedia    = params[1];
    let debug           = params[2];
    
    await exportChatAsXML(displayname, includeMedia, debug);
}

async function exportChatAsXML(displayname, includeMedia, debug)
{

    let chat = (await WPP.chat.list()).find(m => m.contact && m.contact.name && m.contact.name.includes(displayname));
    await WPP.chat.openChatBottom(chat.id);
    let msgs = await WPP.chat.getMessages(chat.id, {count : -1});

    const log = (obj) => debug && console.log(obj);
    
    log('Total messages: ' + msgs.length);

    let count=msgs.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        log('Message number: ' + i);

        let message = msgs[i];
        let xml='';
        xml+= '<message>';
        xml+= '<sender>'+ message.from.user +'</sender>';
        xml+= '<receiver>'+ message.to.user +'</receiver>';

        xml+= '<type>'+ (message.type || '') +'</type>';

        if(message.type == 'chat')
        {
            xml+= '<body>'+ message.body +'</body>';
        }

        if(message.type != 'chat' && includeMedia) 
        {
            xml+= '<media>';
            xml+= '<caption>'+ (message.caption || '') +'</caption>';
            xml+= '<filename>'+ (message.filename || '') +'</filename>';

            log('Downloading media');

            try
            {
                let mediabody = await mediatoBase64(message.id);
                xml+= '<MediaDownloadStatus>success</MediaDownloadStatus>';
                xml+= '<base64>'+ mediabody +'</base64>';
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                xml+= '<base64></base64>';
                xml+= '<MediaDownloadStatus>fail</MediaDownloadStatus>';
            }
            xml+= '</media>';
        }

        xml+= '</message>';

        alert('before'); //this is still shown

        //where is JSCallbackReceiver defined? it is from vb6
       window.JSCallbackReceiver.OnWhatsAppXMLReceived(i, count, xml);
       
       alert('after'); //this is not shown

       xml='';
    }
}


//-----
async function mediatoBase64(msgid) {
    let blob = await WPP.chat.downloadMedia(msgid);
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
}
```

It works fine on my developer's machine, but throws an error on a client's machine:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'OnWhatsAppXMLReceived' of undefined https://web.whatsapp.com/ 80
```

I have added some alerts now to see where exactely it goes wrong.
The alert "before" is shown, the alert "after" is not shown, so the error definitively occurs in

```
   window.JSCallbackReceiver.OnWhatsAppXMLReceived(i, count, xml);
   alert('after');
```

What could I check to see what exactely goes wrong / what is different on the client's machine?

The callback object is defined in VB6 like this:

```
Private m_JSCallback As clsJSCallbackReceiver

Set m_JSCallback = New clsJSCallbackReceiver
Me.webkit1.AddObject "JSCallbackReceiver", m_JSCallback
```

Does the error message mean that the browser does not find the object that I added via `AddObject`?

I am using [mobileFx webkit browser](https://www.webkitx.com/) which is based on Chromium, but I guess that is not important.

This is what the class `clsJSCallbackReceiver` looks like in VB6:

```
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub OnWhatsAppXMLReceived(ByVal uIndex As Long, ByVal uCount As Long, ByVal uXml As String)

     Debug.Print("I was called!")
    
 End Sub

 Public Sub SaySomething(ByVal u As String)
     MsgBox(u)
 End Sub
```

Thank you!

Edit:

I only happens when compiled.
When I run it in the VB6 IDE, it works fine.

After the error occurs, I can still call

```
m_JSCallback.SaySomething("Hello!")
```

, and it will work.

So the object is still alive.
It is just not connected to the browser, I guess.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know close to nothing about Javascript, so I just looked for irregularities and the blank before the 80 in the error message looks suspicious to me: ```https://web.whatsapp.com/ 80```

Comment: I noticed that, too, but didn't know what to make out of it.

Comment: Seems to me like a racing condition, when is " window.JSCallbackReceiver" set? Do you know for a certain that it is set before a property of that is called? Not that is it loaded async for an example. window.JSCallbackReceiver still null/undefined when called from console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/set-up-vb-project-using-class), which says this about an example they've given:

"Next, since the Instancing property of the class is PublicNotCreatable, the project must provide a way for a client to instantiate the object. Add a new function in a standard module. Where clsEmployee is the name of the class of interest. Also, this should not be a private module."

And your code seems to contradict that.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping you were right. I have declared it any way I could imagine: In a public module, in a form, with and without events, but it didn't change anything. I can still m_JSCallback.DoSomething. That works. So the object is still alive, it's just not connected to the webbrowser.

Comment: Okay so, I may have found it: "Visual Basic 6.0 developers, please note that if you wish to expose a local VB6 Class to JavaScript, you must compile your executable as ActiveX EXE. Standard executables will only work while in Visual Basic 6.0 IDE but not if you compile them." from: [webkitx](https://www.webkitx.com/doc/light/WebKitXCEF3Lib~WebKitXCEF3~AddObject.html)

Comment: Wow!!!! I never expected that.

Comment: You have helped me sooooo much. Thank you!!!! I did that now, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The error message explain you that at the line:

```
window.JSCallbackReceiver.OnWhatsAppXMLReceived(i, count, xml);
```

the `window.JSCallbackReceiver` object is undefined.

First to get rid of this error message you chould replace this line with:

```
if (window.JSCallbackReceiver) {
    window.JSCallbackReceiver.OnWhatsAppXMLReceived(i, count, xml);
}
```

This will not solve you problem, because it just suppress error.

So you then need to investigate why `SCallbackReceiver` is undefined on your customer's browser.

To get more help, you need to provide source code about `JSCallbackReceiver`.

Comment: I have already posted the source code of JSCallbackReceiver. It is just this little class. There is nothing that can go wrong with it.